# If the output of an array is >1 <b> the result

Tags: php, html

The output of `'qty'` is a number either 1 or greater, if it is greater than 1 then I want to add some html such as `<b>` around the result, how do I do that with an `if` statement?

```
<?php echo $vertSpacing . $pdfItem['qty'] . ($isNotLast ? '' : $vertSpacing) ?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the entire code to this:

```
<?php
$hasQty=$pdfItem['qty']>=1;
if($hasQty)
    echo '<b>';
echo $vertSpacing . $pdfItem['qty'] . ($isNotLast ? '' : $vertSpacing);
if($hasQty)
    echo '</b>'
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Will accept as an answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<?php echo $vertSpacing . ($pdfItem['qty'] >= 1 ? '<b>' . $pdfItem['qty'] . '</b>' : $pdfItem['qty']) . ($isNotLast ? '' : $vertSpacing) ?>
```

Comment: @MikeK, yes.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= ($pdfItem['qty'] >= 1 ? '<b>': '') . $vertSpacing . $pdfItem['qty'] . ($isNotLast ? '' : $vertSpacing) . ($pdfItem['qty'] >= 1 ? '</b>': '') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $hasSome = ( intval( $pdfItem[ "qty" ] ) >= 1 ) ? true : false;

    if ( $hasSome === true ) echo "<b>";
    echo $vertSpacing . $pdfItem[ "qty" ] . ($isNotLast ? '' : $vertSpacing);
    if ( $hasSome === true ) echo "</b>";
?>
```